# Facebook comments based of URL query

Tags: html, facebook

I'm currently making a website and it has facebook comments embedded. I made myself a moderator, but only had moderator access to the page with the id of 4 (?id=4) and no other pages.

I used

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="My id*"/>
```

*May not of been my ID, I got it from a photo url

And then I tried

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="My app ID*"/>
```

Again, may not of been the correct ID, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue) though

For my embed code, I have

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo "http://www.example.com" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>" data-width="800" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong and how I could become admin on all pages?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: Can you post an example page, have you got `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>` on your `main` template page?

Comment: Do I have to add my app id on the index page?

Comment: I have it on all pages apart from the index

Comment: So if you go to `?id=1` or `?id=2` you can still see the `fb:app_id` property when you view the source of the page?

Comment: Yes. Its on all pages, but it only registers on ?id=4

Comment: Probably won't be able to help without a working example.

Comment: In your App settings, I think you may have set the URL to `id=4` - https://graph.facebook.com/509139419152080

Comment: If I change it to just the domain, will it use the same comments on all pages? I want it to be separate for each page.

Comment: I believe (?) it should treat them differently, as although it's the same page, you're passing a different `ID` in.

Comment: So change the app url to just the domain? I don't want to risk losing all the comments :/

Comment: Yep - change it to the domain, and `id=3`, `id=4` will be treated as unique pages.

Comment: So I just change data-href="<?php echo "http://www.example.com" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>" to data-href="http://example.com"

Comment: Keep that, because you need it to update the site url for each `page ID`, but in the `Facebook application settings` you need to change the URL  to `example.com`, rather than, `example.com/index.php?id=4`

Comment: Nope. That just merged all the comments, and I wasn't even mod :(

Comment: Oh wait, I changed the website, not the app :P

Comment: Changed the app, nothing happened...

Comment: You have an error - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhexxitserverlist.com You need to fix that

Comment: "You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a valid integration URL." I'm just not even sure...

Comment: Ok. I've got the domain added, there are no errors, just warnings. But I'm still only mod on id 4!

Comment: Just double check something, are you added as an `Administrator` here : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/572312579488075/roles?ref=nav ??

Comment: Yip I am an administrator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/) to download the php sdk for Facebook, and through that you can make your own comment boxes and still make user use facebook login credentials

Comment: Looks like Ill just go with this, I have plenty of time. Also, nice name :P